# Program to find biggest of four numbers using nested-if

Tags: c, nested-if

Sir/Ma'am,
I do not know what may be that I'm doing wrong. Logic- wise everything appears correct to me. The braces seem placed in the correct positions as well. Then why is it that I'm receiving the following error messages?

> 32    8    [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
>   33  2   [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'return'
>   34  1 [Error] expected declaration before '}' token

What am I doing wrong with this particular program? And, I was hoping for a correction using the same statements, and not any other.

Please help!

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, big;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    if (a >b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
            big = a;
            else
            big=d;
        }
        else
           {
           if(c>d)
            big = c;
            else
            big = d;
        }
        else
            if(b>c)
            {
                if(b>d)
                big = b;
                else
                big = d;
            }
    }
    printf("\n The biggest number is %d", big);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Constructors and Destructors are not a part of the C language.

Comment: You can't have an 2nd else statement after another else statement.  Around line 23 you need an else if statement.

Comment: You're using a C++ compiler.  You must therefore use an ISO-conformant definition of `main`: `int main()`.  In addition to the `else` issue (which is just a misplaced `}` that could have been avoided if you indented code properly), you are missing some logic.  Note the "fixed" program compiles but doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/RoWlRj

Comment: Of course, since this is C++, you could just use `int big = std::max(std::max(a, b), std::max(c, d))`

Comment: This is C, not C++. But yes, the compiler is both C & C++ compatible. @paddy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ternary operator` to solve your problem. Thus, the code simplifies to

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    const int big1 = (a > b) ? a : b;
    const int big2 = (c > d) ? c : d;
    int big = (big1 > big2) ? big1 : big2;

    printf("\n The biggest number is %d", big);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know what may be that I'm doing wrong. Logic-wise everything appears correct to me.

There are some syntactic errors, though. A construct like

```
// ...
if ( a > c ) {
    // ...
}
else {               // <----
    // ...
}
else if ( b > c ) {
    // ...
}
```

Is not valid in C.

It's unclear to me how the OP was planning to structure the nested `if`s in order to solve the task, but before going on, I'd suggest to write some simple tests to verify the correctness of the algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Prototype of the function which returns the biggest out of the four arguments
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d);

// Helper function used to verify the correctness of the results
int test_(int a, int b, int c, int d, int expected)
{
    int result = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    if ( result != expected )
    {
        printf("FAILED - Expected: %d (given %d, %d, %d and %d), instead of %d.\n", 
               expected, a, b, c, d, result);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Test runner
int main(void)
{
    int failed = 0;

    // The function should be able to find the biggest regardless of its "position"
    failed += test_(1, 2, 3, 4,  4);
    failed += test_(4, 3, 2, 1,  4);
    failed += test_(2, 1, 4, 3,  4);
    failed += test_(3, 4, 1, 2,  4);

    // The function should manage negative values
    failed += test_(1, -2, -3, -4,    1);
    failed += test_(-4, -3, -2, -1,  -1);
    failed += test_(0, -3, -1, -2,    0);

    // The function should manage duplicate values
    failed += test_(1, -2, 1, 2,      2);
    failed += test_(-4, -3, -3, -5,  -3);
    failed += test_(1, 1, 1, 1,       1);

    if ( failed == 0 )
        puts("So far so good.");

    return 0;
}

// A simple implentation.
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int big = a;
    if ( b > a )
        big = b;
    if ( c > big )
        big = c;
    if ( d > big )
        big = d;
    return big;    
}
```

You can test it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7ZWUnBhw9EmGoy6X) and try to rewrite the function using nested `if` statements, if you want. Maybe something like

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if ( b > a )
    {
        if ( d > c )
        {
            if ( b > d )
                return b;
            else
                return d;
        }
        else // d <= c
        {
            if ( b > c )
                return b;
            else
                return c;
        }            
    }
    else // b <= a
    {
        // You got the idea...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the ternary operator instead of if-else statements it works the same as if-else you can check how [ternary operator](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_conditions_shorthand.asp) works.

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
     return (a < b ? ((b > c)? ((b > d)? b:d) :((c > d)? c: d))  : ((a < c)? ((c > d)? c: d) : ((a > d) ? a : d)));
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank for the info, I'll try my best next time

Answer (score 0):

One more if statement has to be added. You forgot it, that's why it's giving an error

```
else
    if(c>d)
        cout << c << "is greater number" << endl;
    else
        cout << d << "is greater number" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you use an obsolete syntax `main()` without a return type: your compiler rejects it because it is configured to compile C++ code.
- the program is not indented properly: this prevents visual analysis which would show that you missed some braces and a few cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, big;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    if (a > b) {
        if (a > c) {
            if (a > d) {
                big = a;
            else
                big = d;
        } else {
            if (c > d)
                big = c;
            else
                big = d;
        }
    // missing }
    else
    // missing {
        if (b > c) {
            if (b > d)
                big = b;
            else
                big = d;
        } // missing else branch
    }
    printf("The biggest number is %d\n", big);
    return 0;
}
```

- you should check for `scanf()` conversion failures and handle them gracefully.

Here is a completed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d, big;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4)
        return 1;
    if (a > b) {
        if (a > c) {
            if (a > d) {
                big = a;
            else
                big = d;
        } else {
            if (c > d)
                big = c;
            else
                big = d;
        }
    } else {
        if (b > c) {
            if (b > d)
                big = b;
            else
                big = d;
        } else {
            if (c > d)
                big = c;
            else
                big = d;
        }
    }
    printf("The biggest number is %d\n", big);
    return 0;
}
```

The nested tests can be rewritten using the ternary operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4)
        return 1;
    int big = (a > b) ? (a > c) ? (a > d) ? a : d
                                : (c > d) ? c : d
                      : (b > c) ? (b > d) ? b : d
                                : (c > d) ? c : d;

    printf("The biggest number is %d\n", big);
    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify this using intermediary variables:

```
    int max_ab = (a > b) ? a : b;
    int max_cd = (c > d) ? c : d;
    int big = (max_ab > max_cd) ? max_ab : max_cd;
```

Finally, you can use a more general approach that is easy to extend to more variables:

```
    int big = a > b ? a : b;
    big = big > c ? big : c;
    big = big > d ? big : d;
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you missed the return type of the main() funtion,

2nd you used else block after another else block it was an error the else block is the last block for the if...else,

3rd you missed some conditions to check all the values with all other value

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, big;
    printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    if(a > b) {
        if(a > c) {
            if(a > d)
                big = a;
            else
                big = d;
        }
        else
            big = c;
    }
    else {
        if(b > c) {
            if(b > d)
                big = b;
            else
                big = d;
        }
        else {
            if (c > d)
                big = c;
            else
                big = d;
        }
    }
    printf("\n The biggest number is %d", big);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not consider case when `a <= b` or it places in wrong position (inside `a < b` block).

You can imagine problem in a decision tree similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1QMT.jpg) (3 numbers) for clearer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a, b, c, d, big;
  printf("\n Enter value to a, b, c, d: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

  if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) {
      if (a > d)
        big = a;
      else
        big = d;
    } else {
      if (c > d)
        big = c;
      else
        big = d;
    }

  } else {
    if (b > c) {
      if (b > d)
        big = b;
      else
        big = d;
    }
    else {
      if (c > d)
        big = c;
      else
        big = d;
    }
  }

  printf("\n The biggest number is %d", big);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will you please explain what you did to solve the problem? OP might not notice, and therefore he cannot learn anything from this. Not my down-vote.